# Decide Goldbach's conjcture

Tags: code-golf

Your job is to write a program that determines if [Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) is true. The requirements are this:

- If it is true: Print nothing. Run forever.
- If it is false: Print the *first* counterexample. Halt.

Shortest code wins, but show why it works. **Don't use any Prime built-in functions.**

**Edit:** If you want, include another version that just adds a line that prints what even number you've found a solution to help explain your answer. (It should print 2,4,6,...).

**Note:** If the conjecture get proven or disproven conclusively, then this will become irrelevant, and I might change it to some other similar [open problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics).

Comment: This is (currently) impossible. It is unknown whether the conjecture is true, so we can't print an answer based off of it. Do you mean to test the conjecture on an input?

Comment: @Quincunx it is not said the program must terminate.

Comment: Without a solution to the underlying mathematical problem, we really have no way of knowing what this program's output should be. We can generally judge whether a program should or should not function correctly *in theory*, but we have no way of knowing whether or not it will meet the requirements until we know what (if any) the upper bounds of the conjecture are. Wikipedia says that it's been verified up to 4*10^18, which will fit into a signed 64-bit integer. But, without a solution to the problem, we have no way of knowing whether answers here need to account for numbers beyond int64.

Comment: Well then you have to account for larger numbers.

Comment: Also, why the requirement not to use any prime functions? Brute-forcing an unsolved mathematical problem is hard enough, and you want to pile on primality testing along with it?

Comment: It shouldn't be that difficult to write a prime tester. I didn't want languages with prime-testing built-in to have an advantage.

Comment: True, false, undecidable, and unknown seem to be the four possibilities. You only mention the first two.

Comment: @DavidCarraher If it's undecidable, then it's true, and you must run forever.

Comment: @ike Undecidable != true. Undecidable simply means it is impossible to prove truth or falsehood.

Comment: @Iszi See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27755/knuths-intuition-that-goldbach-might-be-unprovable

Comment: It is true but cannot be proven if it is undecidable.

Comment: There is no way to subject entrees to a *test* as to whether they complete successfully.

Comment: There is no *automated* way, however [humans are smarter than turing machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orch-OR#The_Penrose.E2.80.93Lucas_argument). I will judge them.

Comment: And do you know that you can evaluate every language in which a submission might be made. We've had APL, fish, and a whole host of languages from the Turing tarpit in addition to postscript, forths, dc, and so on.

Comment: Well if it's a language I don't know I might need someone else to judge. That's why I asked you to explain it.

Comment: This question is asking people to code-golf a program that won't terminate. The kerfufle over possible program outcomes, and undecideability is moot: We all know these programs won't terminate. The issue about automated testing doesn't matter much: Most question posers don't have the facility, time, or inclination to test submitted solutions in off-beat languages. We just rely on the programmer's self-reported output to prove it works. Here there'll be no output - but I don't think that really is a big issue- we generally take it all on trust anyway!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's shape-shifting.

Comment: What more information do you want?

Comment: @MtnViewMark, you claim, "We all **know** these programs won't terminate."  Oh, do we?  ;-)

Comment: @DarrenStone As the conjecture has yet to be proven or disproven, strictly speaking, we don't - therein lies 83.6% of our problem.

Comment: We know that any modern computer will die before it hits the 4*10^18 mark.

Comment: @ike Any program that's written to validate or disprove Goldbach by brute-force would be well-served to start beyond that mark, as numbers below it have already been confirmed. Another thing to consider is that conjectures like this, strictly speaking, *cannot* be authoritatively proven by brute-force alone since the expected limit is infinity. Eventually, this means we must be able to process numbers like [Graham's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number#Magnitude) with precise accuracy - which is not only impossible with current technology, but theoretically impossible altogether!

Comment: Well if you're trying to golf it then you're better off starting from the beginning so as not to waste space.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 94

```
require'Prime'
(4..1/0.0).step(2){|x|p=Prime.take x
p x if p.product(p).all?{|y|y[0]+y[1]!=x}}
```

VERY VERY slow and inefficient. Finds all possible sums of primes less than the number, *and* recalculates the primes each iteration! :D

Change `.all?` to `.any?` to see all non-counter-examples (?), which is all even numbers > 2 :P

Comment: Added requirement not to use prime functions.

Comment: @ike voted to close because of that

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 85 (incomplete)

I submit this as a partial answer to the question.

The following program will run until it determines that Goldbach's conjecture is solved. It will then exit and print nothing. I have not yet coded the counterexample-printing in the case of falseness.

```
require'open-uri'
while/Goldbach's conjecture/=~open('http://goo.gl/fuJLr1').read;end
```

Please enjoy.  **:-)**

Comment: aaand... what's the code length?

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge - 0

Works up until the [4 * 10<sup>18</sup> iteration](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) of the loop; after that, I am not sure:

Okay, okay; here is a valid **Python** solution (236 chars):

```python
import sys
def p(a):
 for i in g():
    if a%i!=0:return 0
 return 1
def g():x=2;while 1:x+=1;yield x
for i in g():
 for x in g():
    for y in g():
     if y+x>i:break;if p(x)*p(y):x=i+1
    if x-i:print i;sys.exit()
    if x>=i:break;
```